# Authentification by username in laravel 7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

Hello i want to log in my users by name, i have do this ( the same as the documentation :

```
 public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

[documentation of authenticate by username](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating)

If i want to log in into the form Laravel redirect me to the login form without error message.

In my LoginController.php:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(auth()->attempt(array('name' => $input['name'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
    {
        //If an user is admin and if the account admin have all authorization he can pass et go to the admin pages
        if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 1 && auth()->user()->is_seller == 1 && auth()->user()->is_client == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        //If user is an seller and user have pass the login, he have authorization, he can pass to go on seller dashboard
        }elseif (auth()->user()->is_seller == 1 && auth()->user()->is_client == 1){
            return redirect()->route('seller.dashboard');
        //If the user is an seller he go to the shop page
        } elseif(auth()->user()->is_client == 1){
            return redirect()->route('shop.home');
        }
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login')
            ->with('error','Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
    }
    return route('login');
}
```

I have replace the field name by the name column of users table => name='name'

Answer (score 0):

I have fund my problem.

I have to need to specify the good value for searching pseudo